# How to run linux command from java code?

Tags: java, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux commands from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126116/linux-commands-from-java)

I am developing a Java application where I need to run a linux command from my application. How to do this?

Comment: Yes, but the complaints of the accepted answer there don't necessarily apply to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
/* build up command and launch */
String command = "DO SOMETHING";

try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Runtime.exec() method.

Answer (score 1):

Example of such:

```
String [] arrs = new String [3] ;
arrs[0] = "/bin/bash";
arrs[1] = "-c";
arrs[2] = "rm s*"  ;
pp=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrs);
pp.waitFor();
```

Which removes files starting with s from the directory where the java code is stored.