# Java - execute a program with options, like ls -l

Tags: java, terminal, command

1. In Java, how do I execute a linux program with options, like this:

   `ls -a` (the option is -a),

   and another: `./myscript name=john age=24`

   I know how to execute a command, but cannot do the option.

Comment: So which API are you using to execute the command?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html looks promising

Comment: There are SO many options... :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux commands from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126116/linux-commands-from-java)

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute an external process, take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html&ei=MkkkUNiDKq-ViQeRyoFg&usg=AFQjCNHSAWl4szO37Qonu5enNH3U4ss__A&sig2=qkqiqDqc46aUKpr31WPxkQ) and just because it almost answers your question, [Using ProcessBuilder to Make System Calls](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/java-tip-of-day-using-processbuilder-to.html)

**UPDATED with Example**

I ripped this straight from the list example and modified it so I could test on my PC and it runs fine

```
private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        int c = in.read();
        if (c == -1) {
            break;
        }
        out.write((char) c);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

//        if (args.length == 0) {
//            System.out.println("You must supply at least one argument.");
//            return;
//        }

    args = new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "dir", "C:\\"};

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    copy(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + process.exitValue());
}
```

Comment: I am aware if ProcessBuilder, but kinda struggling with it. Any concrete example? How would you set the String array in the contructor of ProcessBuilder? `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(.......)` How to I set command and args inside the dot dot dot?

Comment: I'd have a read of the example, it literally does what you want.  `ProcessBuilder` takes either a `List<String>` or array of `String` arguments, the first is the command to be executed, the remainder at the command parameters (each one should be a separate parameter)

Comment: You might also like to have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java for executing shell commands

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons has a library built to handle this type of thing. I wish I knew about it before I coded something like this by hand. I found it later on. It takes options in various formats for a command line program.

[Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/)