# buffered reader freezes but not exception

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader

```
private static void runner() {
    try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        //Runtime rt = Runtime();
        //rt.getRuntime();

        String command = "C:\\dummy.exe";
        //command = "cmd";
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);

        BufferedReader processOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter processInput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));
        String commandToSend;
        //commandToSend = "dir\n";

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a command");
        commandToSend = reader.nextLine(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.

        System.out.println(commandToSend);
        processInput.write(commandToSend+"\r\n");
        processInput.flush();
        int lineCounter = 0;
        String line ="";
        boolean go2 =true;
        while(go2)
        {
               line = processOutput.readLine();
        //System.out.println("2");  

            if(line == null) {
                System.out.println("\n\ndone\n");
                go2=false;
            }


            //System.out.println(go2);
            System.out.println(++lineCounter + ": " + line); 
        }
        }
        reader.close();
        processInput.close();
        processOutput.close();
        pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("done\n");
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

that is the output

```
Enter a command
dir
dir

3: 
12: 02/03/2018  02:35 PM               301 .classpath
13: 02/03/2018  02:35 PM               382 .project
14: 02/03/2018  02:35 PM    <DIR>          .settings
15:
16: 02/03/2018  02:36 PM    <DIR>          src
17:                2 File(s)            683 bytes
18:               5 Dir(s)  702,993,940,480 bytes free
19:
```

it freezes here ^
it freezes at the line line =processOutput.readline()
I have tried multiple print statements and found that after line 19 it freezes but doesnt throw an error.
I think the issue has to deal with how buffered nulls
I have snipped some of the output which explains the gap in numbers
but the main thing to illustrate is that it does not freeze on newlines
just at the end

Comment: Yes, it's probably waiting for more input (or output from the process as the case may be)

Comment: I'd recommend having a read through [How to Run a Shell Command in Java](http://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java) and maybe even [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893469/java-execute-a-program-with-options-like-ls-l/11893495#11893495) for some basic ideas

Comment: Now, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778) is probably a little beyond what you're looking for, but it demonstrations a concept of interacting with a running process

Comment: It *blocks,* waiting for more process output. Try closing the process's input.

Comment: ok thanks for responding so quickly and i will read through your link but just looking at what im dealing with. how can I escape the loop or  tell when the input stream ends. This is a smaller portion of a larger project.

Comment: Im reading the example now, but i should also mention my intention is to change the input from scanner and it is also not to create a terminal window like theirs does.

Comment: ohh thank you at EJP i adjusted and got a modified output

Comment: I will post the edit.But now I will check to see new issues.