# how to transfer file from server linux to another server linux java code

Tags: java, linux

I want to transfer file from server linux to another server linux using java application. anyone give me a solution or example .

Comment: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons Net API

Some sample programs are given at below links

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java
http://www.journaldev.com/661/java-ftp-upload-example-using-apache-commons-net-api

[This](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/ServerToServerFTP.java) should be perfect solution for you, it is server to server file transfer example.

Answer (score 0):

Given that both systems are Linux, I think that a simpler solution would be to use "scp".

All you need to do is set up some SSH keys, and then run this command from the Java application:

```
    scp /path/to/source_file user_name@hostname:/path/to/dest_file
```

See this Question on how to run a Linux command from Java:

- [Linux commands from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126116/linux-commands-from-java)

This has the following advantages:

- You can put the file anywhere on the remote system ... in one operation.
- You don't need to set up an FTP server on the remote system.
- The transfer can be done securely.

The only caveat with this approach is that you have to manage the SSH keys.  In particular, you have to choose between:

- using a key pair with a pass-phrase which is more secure but requires some slightly tricky stuff to unlock the key (e.g. lookup "man ssh-agent"), or
- using a key pair without a pass-phrase which presents a security risk if your private key leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Linux commands to transfer files from one system to another.
These can be done in two ways.

From source system to destination system (Push mechanism)

```
scp scp /path/to/source_file user_name@hostname:/path/to/dest_file
```

From destination system to source system (Pull mechanism)

```
scp user_name@hostname:/path/to/dest_file /path/to/source_file
```

For doing this through java you can follow the below link.

[SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)